# How do I get the type of a member through reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

I need to read the value of a member (it may be a field or a property) whose name is passed to my method. This is how I retrieve the MemberInfo:

```
MemberInfo member = itemType.GetField(fieldName) as MemberInfo ?? itemType.GetProperty(fieldName) as MemberInfo;
```

Next, I'd like to check the type of the member (field/property) that has been found. What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `PropertyType` property of `PropertyInfo` or `FieldType` if `FieldInfo`

```
MemberInfo member = itemType.GetField(fieldName) as MemberInfo ?? itemType.GetProperty(fieldName) as MemberInfo;
Type type = member is PropertyInfo ? ((PropertyInfo)member).PropertyType : ((FieldInfo)member).FieldType;
```

Comment: Actually MemberType returns whether the member is a field, a property or a method... I need to get the type (int, string...) of the returned field or property, as I'm sure that it is either a field or a property.

Comment: So you confirm that there is no way to get it straight out of `MemberInfo`? Not that I find it too strange, since `MemberInfo` may refer to a lot of different entities...

Comment: @Simone no, there's no way. `MemberInfo` serves for other purposes that would not have a type... having a type is something specific of fields and properties

Answer (score 1):

Use [MemberInfo.MemberType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.membertype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
var myProp = type.GetField(fieldName) ...;
var type = myProp.MemberType;
```

EDIT: To get the data-type of the property field you have also to distinguish between properties and fields:

```
var type = (myProp is PropertyInfo ?) 
    (pyProp as PropertyInfo).PropertyType) : 
    (myProp as FieldInfo).FieldType);
```

Comment: Actually MemberType returns whether the member is a field, a property or a method... I need to get the type (int, string...) of the returned field or property, as I'm sure that it is either a field or a property.

Comment: So you confirm that there is no way to get it straight out of `MemberInfo`? Not that I find it too strange, since `MemberInfo` may refer to a lot of different entities...

Comment: I can´t see any method from `MethodInfo` that serves this purpose. However this is clear, as `MemberInfo` can also represent methods and delegates. So what should such a member return in this case? The return-value? The param-list?

Answer (score 1):

You can get this info from the `FieldType` and `PropertyType` properties of the field and property, respectively, but not (easily) from the `MemberInfo` itself. Here's one way you could write the code, that favors code clarity and not doing unnecessary tasks at run-time over code brevity.

```
void GetInfo(Type itemType, string fieldName) {
    FieldInfo field = itemType.GetField(fieldName);
    MemberInfo member;
    Type memberType;
    if (field != null) {
        member = field;
        memberType = field.FieldType;
    } else {
        PropertyInfo property = itemType.GetProperty(fieldName);
        if (property != null) {
            member = property;
            memberType = property.PropertyType;
        } else {
            member = null;
            memberType = null;
            // or throw an exception
        }
    }
    // do something with member and memberType
}
```

Note that if you only need `memberType` at the end, you can eliminate `member` entirely and make the code that much shorter.